# SATA Switch Drive

Tags: multi-boot, sata, switch

So I recently acquired an SATA Switch Drive 
... [http://www.amazon.com/Drive-Switch-Controller-Orico-HD-PW6101/dp/B005NVV2GC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NVV2GC)

Now the problem I'm wondering is that is not compatible with the SATA cables I have with  my
4 SSD... The SATA Cables port measure 1 inch and their label as SATA , but the cables I have which are generic SATA measure 1/2 inch ...

Now According to the Instructions I'm supposed to plug the cables provided to the port of my SSD but the port of the SSD is 1/2 inch and the cable is 1 inch wide.

My question what is the difference between the SATA I have and the one they provided because
they aren't compatible ?

I'm currently running Ubuntu on one SSD and Windows 7 on Another and also Windows 8 on another and I thought this switch could help so I didn't had to plug in/out every time to switch ...

These are the photos of the cable ports

http://postimg.org/gallery/8tatjp3y/3df07b9d/

Comment: Can you just use the SATA cables you already have? The only reason you couldn't is the end you plug into this switch requires a special connector which shouldn't be the case since were talking about what basically amounts to a SATA controller bypass allowing any single drive to be the active drive.

Comment: actually I can't, The cables they provided are supposed to connect my SSD but the ports of my SSD's are smaller than the port of the cables. The ports of the cables are 1 inch and the ports of my SDD are 1/2 inch.

Comment: @Chis - You didn't fully read what I wrote, instead of the supplied cables, use the cables you recieved with you SSDs instead.

Answer (score 1):

The cables that are supposed to come with it (judging by the Amazon pictures) have both SATA parts, the 1/2" data connector, and the 1" power connector.

[image: SATA adapter cable]

I think perhaps you need to familiarize yourself with SATA connectors a little better, and then determine if they included all the cables you need.

Comment: I have plenty of SATA of cables and yes the picture you provided me doesn't match to the actual product I received. The connectors are label as SATA and even have the same shape of a SATA "L" shape the only difference is that they are 1 inch wide rather than 1/2 and inch. The cables provided comes with 3 SATA 1 inch wide port at one end and at the other end the "white" square that plug to the drive.

Comment: Then they screwed up and you'll need to send the product back and exchange it for one that has the right cables.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing SATA power connectors (the wide ones) and SATA data connectors (the 1/2" ones). The switch you are looking at is for switching power. I have been unable to locate one which switches data and power, or even data alone.

Comment: Same answer as been done 9 years ago.